# How can I download data from just one of the DVC repositories?

Tags: github, version-control, dataset, mlops, dvc

I have a project that uses several databases, to avoid versioning huge files in git, I used DVC to manage it on gdrive.

I followed the following step by step on DVC

> Start DVC (dvc init)

> dvc add #dataset zip#

> dvc remote add --default #drive_name# gdrive://#Folder ID#

> dvc push

for each dataset. But when I try to upload such a data set individually through the

> dvc pull --remote #drive_name#

it simply downloads all the files to my machine and not just the ones I specified, I've already run a dvc remote list and even seen in gdrive that the files are separated. Why can't I get them individually?

Comment: How exactly are you specifying remotes per dataset? Is it part of the `.dvc` file itself?

Comment: by the config file on .dvc directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store certain parts of the DVC project in some remote, and other part in a different remote storage there are two way to do this (or a mix of those).

1. (I would recommend this). Use the `remote:` field in the [`.dvc` files](https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/project-structure/dvc-files#output-entries) or [`dvc.yaml`](https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/project-structure/dvcyaml-files#output-subfields). For example:

```yaml
stages:
  transpose:
    ...
    outs:
      - columns.txt
          remote: myremote
```

or:

```yaml
outs:
  - md5: a304afb96060aad90176268345e10355
    path: data.xml
    desc: Cats and dogs dataset
    remote: myremote
```

In this case, you don't have to use `--remote` for `dvc pull` or `dvc push` - DVC will know automatically which remote to use for each datasets or models or output in general.

2. You can indeed use `--remote`. But in this case (and that's where probably the issue is in your case), you would need to always carefully use `dvc push` to avoid by mistake pushing all data to a default remote storage. Always do `dvc push --remote <dataset>`. Or even don't use `--default`, don't even specify a default remote in this case. As you can see this can be a bit tedious tbh.

In both options, I would avoid creating a default remote (unless you have some objects that you want to always go to some default). Also, yes, you still need to use `dvc remote add ...` commands to create all these named remotes.